# Redirect PHP after script is run

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, submit

I have a script that submits emails entered into a form to a database and I am wondering if there is a way to redirect the PHP script after the email has been submitted?

my script is -

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","User","Pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("emails", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO mlist (email)
VALUES
('$_POST[email]'')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

please could someone give clear instructions as I am learning PHP still.

Comment: If you don't output anything at all; `header(“Location: http://www.example.com/redirect/to/otherpage_or_samepage.php?with=different_variables”);` Be careful though, if you do output something and then send a different header, you'll get an error...

Answer (score 3):

To take this redirect one step further. The header "location" should be used with a 302 response code instead of a classical 200 response code. Thios response code is 'global' to the HTTP response.
302 means 'redirect'. Most browser handle the location header even without the 302 response code, but you should set it (it could help for example ajax handling of your response).

```
header("Location: /foo.php",TRUE,302);
```

Now one step more. In fact a 303 response code (see-other) is a better redirect response code. It's called as well the **redirect after post**. This special redirect means for your browser that it's not really a redirect because the page he asked whas in the wrong place, but that it's really a redirect because after your POST action you need a new page result.

```
header("Location: /foo.php",TRUE,303);
```

**Edit:** as stated by thirtydot, a better usage is absolute url in the redirect

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/foo.php",TRUE,303);
```

Remember that POST implies potential data changes (that GET request should'nt imply). A POST followed by a 303 is the right way to go, and will prevent your BACK button reposting the same request.

Comment: You shouldn't use relative redirect locations, see [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30). Of course in practice, they probably are supported pretty much everywhere.

Comment: you're right, it was a fast copy-paste from php manual. Thanks for that note.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$url = 'http://your.redirect.url';
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mysql_select_db("emails", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO mlist (email) VALUES ('$_POST[email]'')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_close($con);

header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: @jakenoble: Can't tell which one of us is more  innovative :) But you can tell my hand is faster if not the fastest :))

Comment: But doesnt heade(''); Only work if you havent run the script yet?

Answer (score 1):

This code taken from the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) manual page will redirect to another page on the same domain and in the same directory:

```
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect in the controller.

header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html');

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location http://www.example.com");
```

That will redirect the browser to example.com, note that you can only use this if output has not already been sent to the browser, e.g make sure you have `echo`, `print` or `var_dump` statements before you use `header()`

Answer (score 0):

Add send header function

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","User","Pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("emails", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO mlist (email)
VALUES
('$_POST[email]'')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }else{
header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
}

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Or send javascripts with code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","User","Pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("emails", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO mlist (email)
VALUES
('$_POST[email]'')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }else{

echo "<script>";
    echo "window.location.href= '".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."';";
echo "</script>";

}

mysql_close($con)
?>
```